# How can kdump reliably write into /var/crash

Tags: kernel, dump, corruption

I am not clear why kdump can write reliably into /var/crash when the file system might not be in a clean state.  Are the Linux ext2/3/4 file systems highly immune to file system corruption during crash?

The underlying file system could have been corrupt under the crashed kernel.  Writing vmcore directly under the dump-capture kernel into such a file system seems dangerous ... even if you run fsck or flush the file system cache from within the crashed kernel's address space.

Comment: kdump writes to a special place in memory.
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kdump/kdump.txt  When the new kernel is booted, it can copy this reserved memory.

Comment: Peter, i think the doc is saying that booting the dump-capture kernel preserves the vmcore of the crashed kernel.  however, i was asking how the dump-capture kernel could reliably write the vmcore onto the file system.  Please correct me if I misunderstood what you were saying.

Comment: The vmcore is not written to the file system when it is dumped.  It is instead preserved in that special place in memory.  There are files that are written to the file system after the new kernel is booted and the system state is sane.  See the 'crash' utility for info on that.

Comment: Peter, I cannot find any document that would corroborate your statement above.  The scheme you described seems unlikely for two reasons.  First, the dump-capture kernel is booted not via a soft reboot thus it is able to preserve the content of the memory. As far as I know, the reboot after capturing the dump is a soft reboot that will probably reset content in the DRAM.  Second, there is no guarantee the crashed vmcore can fit in "that special place" in physical memory (even if you consider compression) that could be retrieved later.

Comment: http://lse.sourceforge.net/kdump/documentation/ols2oo5-kdump-paper.pdf
Quote from paper: "Kdump added the functionality to copy the contents of the ﬁrst 16 MB to a reserved memory area called backup region. Memory for the backup region was reserved during the ﬁrst kernel’s boot time, and location and size of the backup region was speciﬁed using kernel conﬁg options. Kdump also copied over the CPU register states to an area immediately after the backup region during a crash event [03]."

Comment: The best documentation might be to look at the source code in the kernel where the kdump memory region parameters are used.

Comment: Peter, thanks a lot for the helpful links.  The paper you linked looks like an excellent read.  I was probably not clear in my original question, which I have just modified.  My question was not on how kdump can actually capture vmcore (even though I don't fully understand the details).  My question was more on why kdump can write into a file system that is not properly synced due to a kernel panic.  I do agree reading the source code would be the best approach, and I might take that up at some point.

Comment: I don't think kdump can write to the file system after a kernel panic, hence the need to write to raw memory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it necessarily can *reliably* write to `/var/crash`. (For example, if bad blocks caused the panic on a failing hard disk drive.) This is why there are remote destination options for capturing the core, including SSH and NFS.

See [29.2.3.2. Configuring the Target Type](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-kdump-configuration-cli.html)